# VoIP Network Test App for Android

Tags: gratis, android, network-monitor, voip

I am testing VoIP (Voice over Internet Protocol) on Android devices with mixed success.

I experience dropouts, clipped words, garbled speech, and latency.  Sometimes it works great, sometimes it does not.

I would like to diagnose what is going on to see if I can find one or more solutions.

What I (think I) need is an Android app that will measure network transmit/receive values relevant to VoIP.  From what I have researched so far, one measurement that is important is low ping times as well as *consistency* of those ping times.

Note that there are many Android "ping tools", but sending a handful of pings over a period of a few seconds does not seem to be a good VoIP diagnostic tool.

Is there an Android app that will measure, and hopefully graph, network measurements that are relevant to VoIP diagnostics?

Requirements:

1. Free of charge (gratis)
2. Works on Android KitKat

Preferences (not required):

1. No advertisements
2. No unnecessary permissions

Answer (score 1):

Not tested myself, but **[SIP Voip Checker](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antisip.firewallvoipchecker)** might be what you're looking for:

- **Free of charge (gratis):** Check.
- **Works on Android KitKat:** 3.0+, so Check.
- **No unnecessary permissions:** Only [INTERNET](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#INTERNET) and [ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) – Check.
- **No advertisements:** I've not tested it, but I strongly think so (arguing by the permissions, at least no intrusive ad networks).

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>*SIP Voip Checker* (source: [Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antisip.firewallvoipchecker); click images for larger variants)</sup>

*SIP Voip Checker* describes itself as *an app to test SIP accounts and SIP network access.* I'm not sure it covers all your needs (e.g. I don't see the *graphing* part covered), but at least it's doing some of the VoIP specific things. So let's check an alternative:

---

**[Voiptester: Network Test Tool](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cst.voitester)** seems to cover pretty much all of what you need:

> Displayed metrics:
>
> - PING roundtrip time
> - RTP packet loss
> - RTP jitter
> - RTP packet count
> - RTP codec type
> - HTTP up and download speeds
> - Allowed firewall protocols: SIP/UDP, SIP/TCP, RTP, RTCP, ICMP, HTTP
> - TCP/IP configuration
> - Device details

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>*Voiptester* (source: [Google Play](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cst.voitester); click images for larger variants)</sup>

- **Free of charge (gratis):** Check.
- **Works on Android KitKat:** 1.6+, so Check.
- **No unnecessary permissions:** Well, not quite "check" here: it additionally wants your location, access to your storage, and phone state. All of those can be explained, though: phone state might be included automatic (Android 1.6), storage for storing stats, and location might be relevant for test rating (not sure about this one, though).
- **No advertisements:** Again, I've not tested it. Arguing by the permissions, ad modules are possible (location+phone state is a typical combination for that) – but that might be misleading. Looks like definitely worth trying.

Comment: Thanks Izzy!  I can't believe I didn't find those.  Clearly I was using the wrong search terms.  I'll give both of those a try and see if they help.  The second one looks very promising.  The big thing they seem to be missing is graphing, but maybe they can still get the job done.

Comment: Glad it's useful to you! Search terms on Appbrain: "sip test" :) Feel free to update with useful details. Maybe the app supports exporting results as `.csv`, which then could serve as base for graphing with other tools (e.g. office apps). Good luck with it!

Comment: So far, I've tried the 2nd app you recommended, Voiptester.  It's quite good, but limited.  The glaring flaw is that the server cannot be changed.  It only lets you know measurements for connecting to a single VOIP server in Germany.  The jitter it reports is amazingly low... I don't know if it's accurate.  It also has no graphing.  Despite all that, the information it provides is the exact type of information I want... but being restricted to a single server makes it much less useful.

Comment: Sorry to read that – I must have missed that restriction in the description. Maybe contact the dev and ask for a possibility to change that/make it configurable? Otherwise, you can always use my above search-pattern on Appbrain to check for alternatives – though these two have been the best candidates I found (on the first few pages, admittedly).